The simplest of set questions, show A may be a subset of A.
Show that $A \subseteq A$.
The answer is by definition, A may contain additional elements than A.
Something to do with the inclusion of the empty set?
(Pure and Applied Undergraduate texts) Fundamentals of Mathematical Analysis

This is a very good exercise to practice using the formal definitions of mathematical relations rather than our intuitive understanding of them. The formal definition of $X\subseteq Y$ is "for every object $z$, if $z\in X$ then $z\in Y$".

"A may contain additional elements than A"?! No!!!

when you say "for every object z" does z exist more than once as a label or is it just one label? Are set items labels on objects?

Oh! for every object z, A ⊆ A if z ∈ A?

@OpenSauce About your last comment: No. Just use the formal definition of $X\subseteq Y$ in Greg Martin's comment to get (when both $X$ and $Y$ are $A$) that $A\subseteq A$ means "for every object $z$, if $z\in A$ then $z\in A$." Then observe that "if $z\in A$ then $z\in A$" is always true, no matter what $z$ and $A$ are. So $A\subseteq A$ is true.
